# Why fetchIntercept.register hits only once on button click in redux-saga pattern?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am using fetch-intercept to intercept all the http-requests in a react application. I added a loader in the app component and show/hide loader on the basis of request/response recieved. Its working fine but when I click the button second time to call the fetch inside saga file, it is not hitting request method inside fetch interceptor.

**interceptor.js**

```
    import fetchIntercept from 'fetch-intercept';
    import createstore from './store';
    const unregister = fetchIntercept.register({
    request: function (url, config) {

        // Modify the url or config here
        let withDefaults = Object.assign({}, config);
        withDefaults.headers = withDefaults.headers || new Headers({
            'AUTHORIZATION': `Bearer shikhabwehfbwefbffbweufwfwf`
        });

        // call to action to show spinner
        createstore.dispatch({
            type: 'SET_LOADER',
            loading: true
        });

        return [url, withDefaults];
    },

    requestError: function (error) {
        createstore.dispatch({
            type: 'SET_LOADER',
            loading: false,
            error: error
        });
        // Called when an error occured during another 'request' interceptor call
        return Promise.reject(error);
    },

    response: function (response) {

        // Modify the reponse object
        createstore.dispatch({
            type: 'SET_LOADER',
            loading: false
        });
        return response;
    },

    responseError: function (error) {
        createstore.dispatch({
            type: 'SET_LOADER',
            loading: false,
            error: error
        });
        // Handle an fetch error
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
});

export default unregister;
```

**Saga.js**

```
export function* fetchNews() {
  try {
    const json = yield fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10').then(results => {
    return results.json();
    });

    unregister();

    yield put({
      type: "NEWS_RECEIVED",
      json: json.results
    });

  } catch (error) {
      yield put({type: "NEWS_RECIEVED_ERROR", error});
  }
}

// watcher
export function* getNewsActionWatcher() {
  yield takeLatest('GET_NEWS', fetchNews); // action , worker
}


export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([getNewsActionWatcher()]);
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getNews } from '../../actions';

const ButtonComponent = ({ getNews }) => (
    <button onClick={getNews}>Get News</button>
);

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getNews: getNews
};

const GetButton = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ButtonComponent);
export default GetButton;
```

Could anyone please help me out with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `dispatch` in `mapDispatchToProps` to dispatch the `GET_NEWS` action.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    getNews: () => dispatch(getNews())
};
```

Another nitpick is that `takeLatest` in `getNewsActionWatcher` will only run one forked task at a time. Killing the previous task once another `GET_NEWS` action is received.

So using `all` effect in `rootSaga()` is not useful.

Comment: How to kill the task when GET_NEWS action is received? I used finally {
    if (yield cancelled()){
      yield put({
        type: "NEWS_RECIEVED_TEST",
        res: 'Lorem ipsum'
      });
    }
  }
But still not working

Comment: all forked generators will return a `Task` object and can be cancelled using `cancel(task)`

Comment: I tried with cancel but it ha same issue. The issue is with the import of a interceptor unregister function. I moved it to app.jsx and it worked fine

Comment: Thanks for your help